# How to click on a <a> element of an <li> of a <ul> using vba?

Tags: html, excel, vba

Here is a piece of code of the HTML page I am working on. [image]

I am trying to programmatically click on the element highlighted in blue in the picture above.

Here is the code I wrote:

```vb
Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Do While objIE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set IeDoc2 = objIE.Document
Set the_input_elements2 = IeDoc2.getElementsByClassName("parent-item")

For Each input_element2 In the_input_elements2
    If input_element2.href = "javascript:directToSearch()" Then
        input_element2.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next input_element2
```

How do I click on an element of a `ul` in HTML using VBA?

When I run this code, nothing happens. No errors but no result.

Comment: `IeDoc2.querySelector("[href^=javascript]").Click`

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your help. But the code you wrote is actually clicking another button ( not the one i want ). Do you know how to make this work?

Comment: @mplungjan since it is not the only button having href= javascript 
The code you gave me is clicking another button

Comment: So add :directToSearch to the string

Comment: I tried doing that @mplungjan but it gives me an error "Could not complete operation due to error 8070000c

Comment: You may need to escape the :

Comment: Or `href*=directToSearch`

Comment: It doesnt work either. I wrote it this way 
IeDoc2.querySelector("[href^=javascriptdirectToSearch()]").Click 
and that way
IeDoc2.querySelector("[href^=javascript:directToSearch()]").Click

Both did not work... did i do something wrong?

Comment: Try `IeDoc2.querySelector("[href*=directToSearch]").Click`

Comment: @mplungjan i am getting the error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Answer (score 0):

Loop all "a" tags inside the ID of the left menu

`IeDoc2.getElementById("accordion-leftmenu").getElementsByTagName("a")`

in the loop check if the `.innerText` is "Advanced Search". click if it is.

```
Dim IeDoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim the_input_elements2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim input_element2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
```

...

```
Set the_input_elements2 = IeDoc2.getElementById("accordion-leftmenu").getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each input_element2 In the_input_elements2
    If input_element2.innerText = "Advanced Search" Then
        input_element2.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next input_element2
```

Edit: Alright, I've tested the code and it works. I did however have to make sure that Two references were checked: "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls".

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it is giving me an error on the first line of your code saying "Object variable or with block variable not set" . I have defined the following 
Dim the_input_elements2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim input_element2 As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim IeDoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Do you know what is causing the error?

Comment: @Ricardo A there's a typo in this: `IeDoc2.getElementsById("accordion-leftmenu").getElementsByTagName("a")` it should be `.getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways to refer to the element you're interested in:

```
'Targeted (if you know exactly at which order the elements appear in the list)
Dim li As HTMLListElement
Set li = IeDoc2.getElementById("accordion-leftmenu")    'get the list item you're interested in...
Debug.Print li.Children(1).innerText                    '...and access its sub-element in a targeted way
Debug.Print li.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).innerText   '...or find all <a></a> elements contained in it and access the one you're interested in, in a targeted way

'Non targeted (you have to search for it)
Dim element As HTMLObjectElement
For Each element In IeDoc2.getElementsByTagName("a")    'loop through all <a></a> elements...
    If element.innerText = "Advanced Search" Then       '...and find the one you're interested in
        Debug.Print element.innerText
    End If
Next element
```

For demonstration purposes the above code just prints the inner text of the element. You can modify it accordingly.

References used: `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

Also on a side note, please post the actual HTML next time rather than a screenshot of it. It would make it easier for people to help you.